# is $S = \{(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) : |x_1| > 0, x_2 < 1, x_3 \not= -2\}$ open closed, or neither

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Is the set open closed or neither:

$S = \{(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) : |x_1| > 0,  x_2 < 1, x_3 \not= -2\}$

I believe it is not closed as if we consider the sequunce of points  $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ where $x_n = (\frac{1}{n} ,0, 0, 0)$, then $x_n \in S$ but $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = (0, 0, 0 ,0) \notin S$

I think the set is open, because since the inequalities are strict, for any $a \in S$ we can pick a neighborhood $B_r (a)$ of small enough radius such that $|x_1| > 0,  x_2 < 1, \text{ and }x_3 \not= -2$. (if we had $ |x_1| \geq 0,  x_2 \leq 1, x_3 \not= -2$ then the set would not be open).

I am wondering if I am correct. Can I improve my argument?

Comment: You are correct. Depending on your audience you could give more detail in showing that $S$ is open, but the essentials are there.

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to write it as intersection of 3 open set

Comment: Choose any point $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$ in this set, and let $0<r<\min\{ |x_1|, |x_2-1|, |x_3|\}$ to get a radius for your ball.

Comment: You can improve your style by specifying "for any $a=( x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in S$" and by being more precise about $\epsilon.$ E.g.,  let $\epsilon =\min ( |x_1|, 1-x_2,|2+x_3|)$..... My edit was for a trivial typo: \lim for lim

Answer (score 1):

Consider sets

(1) $A=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) : |x_1|>0\}$
Function $f((x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4))=x_1$ is continuous and $A=f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}-\{0\})\implies$
$A$ is open as inverse image of open set.

(2) $B=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) : x_3\neq -2\}$
Function $f((x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4))=x_3$ is continuous and $B=f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}-\{-2\})\implies$
$B$ is open as inverse image of open set.

(3) $C=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) : x_2<1\}$
Function $f((x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4))=x_2$ is continuous and $A=f^{-1}((\infty,1))\implies$
$C$ is open as inverse image of open set.

From (1),(2) and (3) $\implies S=A\cap B\cap C$ is open set as intersetion of 3 open sets